# Projector only displays one color

Tags: projector

I have a SharpVision XV-DW100U projector, and I am trying to connect it to my Macbook Air running OS X Yosemite. I connect it to the projector and it displays right for a few seconds, then turns green. It displays fine on other monitors, so I think it may be a projector problem. I confirmed this later by pressing the button labeled RGB/Comp and it turns red. When it's green, it has the letters RGB along with the resolution and projector speed.

Just to clarify, it shows the image, just not the other colors. All other inputs work correctly except for the VGA input 1 and input 2.

Edit 2: cable is all right. It works fine with another monitor. Same goes for adaptor.

Edit 3: projector pins are all right too.

Answer (score 1):

Macbook doesn't have VGA built in, so normally everyone is using DisplayPort to VGA Adapter, which is actually converting digital signal to analogue. The issue might be with converter itself, but if you are saying it's bad only with the Projector, but works with everything else fine - then I assume that Adapter is ok.

I'd suggest you to troubleshoot in order of appearens:

1. Adapter.
2. VGA Cable.
3. Connection slot or pins on the projector input.

To check the adapter is easy - try connecting via different vga cable to any monitor which has it. To check VGA cable you are using - try connecting it to different device, for example other projector or monitor. Clean the pins in VGA slot of projector, it might be some dust got in from ventilation, or whatever.

The single color to me sounds like it's bad contact somewhere, a VGA cable is broken, or with pin connectors. This happens normally when you have analog cable, alike VGA, when one/several color components goes off.

If you projector has other inputs, DVI or HDMI - I'd recommend to use them, instead of analog VGA.

Comment: I know the projector is working, because When I press the RGB/Comp button it switches colors. Although, now that I think about it, you may be right, is there any way to test if it's the projector? And yes, I meant that I am using the DisplayPort to VGA adaptor. If the projector doesn't work, is there any way to do the red/yellow/white cables? I forget what they are called)

Comment: Try to troubleshoot in order of appearance in my answer, @Awesomeness01. I provided the guidelines how to test each of those, hope this will help you.

Comment: I edited the answer with results.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the pins in the VGA cable or inputs on the projector are having some issues. If the image is turning green then your Red and Blue pins in the cable are either disconnected or have not made proper contact with each other.

Try replacing your cable, and try getting your VGA inputs on the projector looked at or replaced by a technician.